# Searching non-primitive types within a struct

Tags: vespa

I need to search within a an array nested in another array. Let's say I have the following document

```
schema foos {

    document foos {

        struct foo {
            field bars type array<string> {}
        }

        field baz type string {
            indexing: summary
        }

        field foos type array<foo> {
            indexing: summary
            struct-field bars { indexing: attribute } // breaks due to non-primitive typing
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to search within the bars field or at least access that field within a rank-profile whilst also being able to search based on baz. My first thought at a solution would be to structure it as follows:

```
schema foos {

    document foos {

        field id type string {
            indexing: summary
        }

        field baz type string {
            indexing: summary | attribute
        }

        field foos type array<reference<foo>> {
            indexing: summary
        }
    }
}
```

```
schema foo {
    document foo {

        field foos_ref type reference<foos> {
            indexing: attribute
        }

        field bars type array<string> {
            indexing: summary | index
        }
    }
    
    import field foos_ref.baz as baz {}
}
```

This would allow me to search within the foo cluster then get the corresponding foos reference, but the overall goal is to provide the user a list of foos documents which would require multiple searches from the list of returned foo documents resulting in slow searches overall.

If there is a recommended way to handle situations like these, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that a reference field used for parent child relationships can only be single value and not an array (https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/schema-reference.html#type:reference). The reference field is specified in the child type to reference the parent. The schemas can be defined as follows, where *foos* is the parent type and *foo* is the child type:

```
schema foos {
  document foos {
    field id type string {
      indexing: summary | attribute
    }
    field baz type string {
      indexing: summary | attribute
    }
  }
}

schema foo {
  document foo {
    field foos_ref type reference<foos> {
      indexing: attribute
    }
    field bars type array<string> {
      indexing: summary | index
    }
  }
  import field foos_ref.baz as foos_baz {}
  import field foos_ref.id as foos_id {}
}
```

Now you can search for *foo* documents using the fields *bars* and *foos_baz* in the query. Use grouping (https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/grouping.html) on the *foos_id* field to structure the result around the *foos* documents instead. This is handled in a single query request.